# Should I specify any path to access the header files in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4.2

I have the source code for a video decoder. The code was executed without any problem on the MAC terminal.

Now, I need to port it on iOS. The source code has around 20 source files and 40 header files. I have created a project in Xcode 4.2 and put all of these in the project folder, without creating separate folders for headers and source files. When I tried building, its giving errors since the source files are not able to access the needed header files.

Is there any path that I need to specify for the headers?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The source code is very huge to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What about :**

- Project Target
- *Build Settings*
- *User Header Search Paths* (set it to your header path)
- *Always Search User Paths* (set it to `YES`)

---

*These steps should (normally) resolve any "header not found"-related issues.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply... Where shall i check for all these settings??